# Cycling through files by filename in Midnight Commander

Tags: linux, file-management, user-interface, midnight-commander, keyboard-navigation

Sorry if I should have posted this as a feature request to mc developers somewhere.

This is such a common and useful functionality I assumed it ought to be there, yet I can't find it.

What I want is to be able to cycle through files and directories listed in the current panel by typing first symbol of it's name. Also, if multiple keys are pushed in quick succession, the marker is moved to the filename starting with that sequence.

I'm aware of command line autocompletion, selecting or filtering by pattern but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Would be convenient to have some of these or similar features:
I'm in whatever directory, contents sorted by whatever. I press "s". Marker jumps to the first listed file/directory which name starts with "s".
Pressing "s" again moves the marker to the next matching entry, if there are more. If this was the last matching entry, continue from the first one.
Pressing "s" then "a" quickly enough moves the marker to the file/directory starting with "sa".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is indeed possible and is called quick search mode. Quoting from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mc):

> The Quick search mode allows you to perform fast file search in file panel. Press C-s or Alt-s to start a filename search in the directory listing.
>
> When the search is active, the user input will be added to the search string  instead  of  the  command  line. [...] When typing, the selection bar will move to the next file starting with the typed letters.

You should also note that this is the default mode when the command prompt is disabled (this is controlled by the variable `command_prompt` in the ini file, default location `~/.config/mc/ini`).